# Publishing python code to Azure worker role without Visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure, azure-worker-roles

We are trying to move away from VM on Azure. We want to host our python code on a Worker Role. With whatever we have gathered so far it seems we requires a visual studio (VS) on Windows machine in order to deploy(host) the python code on a Worker role.

Most of the developers on our project use Ubuntu for writing python code and hence using VS for deploying the python code on Azure seems a little weird to us.

Is there a way by which we can bypass visual studio and deploy the python code directly from our Ubuntu work stations ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can deploy a `.cscfg` file & a `.cspkg` file which includes the python code directly via Azure [portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal#create-and-deploy) or [classic portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy#how-to-deploy-a-cloud-service), please see the details in the inline link.